# Compare and find nearest matching string by iterating rows from same column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and trying to get output iterating over rows from same column

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 'AA,AC,BC,DE'], [2, 'AA,AD,BC,D'], [3, 'A,C,BC,E'],[4, 'AA,AC,BC,DEEE'],[5, 'KK']]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['rowid', 'Col1'])
```

**Output table :**

```
data_out = [[1, 'AA,AC,BC,DE',2,'2,4'], [2, 'AA,AD,BC,D',2,'1,4'], [3, 'A,C,BC,E',1,'1,2,4'],[4, 'AA,AC,BC,DEEE',2,'1,2'],[5, 'KK',0,'NA']]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data_out, columns=['rowid', 'Col1','max_matching#','Rowid'])
```

max_matching# : explanation
Row-1 values : 'AA,AC,BC,DE' matches 2 values('AA','BC') from row2 and matches 1 value('BC') from row-3,
matches 2 values('AA','BC') from row4 and NIL from row5
som max_matching = max matching from all rows(i.e 2,1,2,NA) = 2
Rowid : Explanation
Row-1 values : 'AA,AC,BC,DE' : max matching rows from above explanation i.e row2&row4 (2,4)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your desired output exactly?

Comment: Thank you , my desired out is 'df_out ' which is derived from df

Comment: so you want to know for each row, what are the rows that have the most matches and how many of them do match? if thats correct you may edit your question so that it becomes clearer

Comment: can you please double check the expected output? I get a different one. For example `AA,AC,BC,DE` has 3 matches with `AA,AC,BC,DEEE`

Comment: yes its my mistake , only 'BC' is matching and not 'A' with 'AA' these are not exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your strings to `set`, then compute the distance as a the length of the set intersection between two rows (with help of [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)), finally [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to form the output columns (count and joined indices):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

# convert strings to sets
s = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(',')))

# function to compute length of the set intersection
def compare(a, b):
    return len((a[0]&b[0]))

out = df.merge(
 pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(s.to_frame(), compare)),
              index=df['rowid'], columns=df['rowid'].rename('Rowid'))
   .stack().reset_index(name='count')
   .query('(rowid != Rowid) & (count > 0)')
   .groupby('rowid', as_index=False)
   #.loc[lambda d: d.groupby('rowid')['count'].transform('max').eq(d['count'])]
   .agg({'count': 'max',
         'Rowid': lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))
        })
    .rename(columns={'count': 'max_matching#'}),
  on='rowid', how='left'
)

# optionally fillna
out['max_matching#'] = out['max_matching#'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   rowid           Col1  max_matching#  Rowid
0      1    AA,AC,BC,DE              3  2,3,4
1      2     AA,AD,BC,D              2  1,3,4
2      3       A,C,BC,E              1  1,2,4
3      4  AA,AC,BC,DEEE              3  1,2,3
4      5             KK              0    NaN
```

If you only want to list the ids with the max matches, uncomment the `.loc[lambda d: d.groupby('rowid')['count'].transform('max').eq(d['count'])]` line.

Output:

```
   rowid           Col1  max_matching#  Rowid
0      1    AA,AC,BC,DE              3      4
1      2     AA,AD,BC,D              2    1,4
2      3       A,C,BC,E              1  1,2,4
3      4  AA,AC,BC,DEEE              3      1
4      5             KK              0    NaN
```

Intermediate intersection:

```
pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(s.to_frame(), compare)),
             index=df['rowid'], columns=df['rowid'].rename('Rowid'))

Rowid  1  2  3  4  5
rowid               
1      0  2  1  3  0
2      2  0  1  2  0
3      1  1  0  1  0
4      3  2  1  0  0
5      0  0  0  0  0
```